# How to translate 我买了百多元

Tags: difference

On DuChinese one can read the following sentence

[image]

Here 买 seems to have the same meaning as 花

Any guidance by chinese expert speakers is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The words **买** and **花** do not have the same meanings. 买 is to purchase, but 花 is to spend. For example,

(1) 我**买**了100元的**苹果**。= I bought 100 dollars apples. 100元的 is the adjective of the noun 苹果.

(2) 我**花**了**100元**买苹果。= I spent 100 dollars buying apples. 买苹果 is the purpose complement of the action 花了.

If you only say “我**买**了一百多元”， then it is not a complete sentence, except there is the context in the conversation. It is better to say “我**花**了一百多元”

Comment: Thank You for Your explaination, though I have a hard time to wrap my head around this.... So if I get this right, that's what comes after 但 tells me how I have to interpret the 买？

Answer (score 1):

去年我**買了**一百多元, 但... - Last year, I **made purchases** of hundred dollars and changes, but didn't get much.

今年才**花了**50元, 就... - This year, only/just **spent** 50 dollars, (I) then got a lot.

**Additional Comments:**

Note that this piece of work is present in the speaking form, which often skips words required for clarity for non-native speakers. The first sentence would make better sense if rewritten as:

- 我**買/花了**一百多元, 但好像也沒有(**買到**)什麽東西.

Both "買了" and "花了" are good choices for this sentence. However,   the author chooses the term "買了" to avoid the repetition of the term "花了" in such a short paragraph.

**ADD:**

The repeating of words can be avoided by replacing the second "花" to "用", for both mean the same here.

- 去年我**花了**一百多元, 但好像也沒有**買到**什麽東西. 今年才**用了**50元, 就買到好多(東西).

Comment: Thank You for Your explaination, I need to let sink this in and grow some synapses;-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, in the first sentence, the term "花了" would make more sense than "買了" however, "買了" was chosen to avoid repeating the same word term twice in such a short paragraph.

Comment: I understand, this rule was imparted to me in school as well

Answer (score 1):

我买了一百多元 here is the shorter form of 我买了一百多元的东西， which can be translated as I bought items worth more than 100 yuan.

I don't know where you got this paragraph, but as a native speaker I would say it is normal to say 我买了一百多元的 Or 我花了一百多。

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not an expert in chinese. However I can help :)

It has the regular meanings here for both characters, to buy something vs to spend something.  Lets break the phrases down:

去年 last year

我 I

買了 bought

100多元 more than 100rmb worth/of.

the latter phrase:

今年 this year

オ(typo, probably supposed to be I but that isn't needed either, could be removed)

花了 spend

50元 fifty rmb
(implied already/so far etc).

So its not that 買 has the same meaning as 花 here, but that 花 has a related meaning of spend here.  note the 多-- this is the character that clarifies that you bought this much moneys worth of X vs just stating I spent X amount of money.

Comment: As you could see in @r13's answer, オ is not a typo, but to mean "only / just" to act as a counter distinction of value gained between spending / expending, (i.e. 花了), the larger amount of 100 多元 and spending / expending "only / just" the smaller amount of 50元. So, オ should not be removed, otherwise the counter distinctive significance would be lost.

Comment: @WayneCheah Thank you, I clearly need coffee, I knew this use and was being silly at the moment I typed this, clearly need more coffee before answering questions.

Comment: You're welcome, and though I'm a tea drinker myself, Cheers!